# Key Vault and Azure Table Storage Retrieve

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-keyvault

When doing a simple retrieve from table storage seeking out a successfully encrypted data set, I get the following error:
**Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding**
I have created my key and got my key id successfully through Azure Powershell.  The MS tutorial on this works, but only if the update and retrieve are in the same method call.  When they are called individually through seperate posts/gets, I get the above error.

I'm pulling my hair on this one and starting to suspect it could be a bug within Azure/Table Storage/KeyVault (encryption).  I appreciate if anyone knows anything about this.

```
            RsaKey key = new RsaKey("mykeyid");

        TableRequestOptions retrieveOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
        {
            EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(key, null)
        };

        TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve(patientId.ToUpper(), questionnaireId.ToUpper());
        var answers = answersTable.Execute(operation, retrieveOptions, null);
```

Comment: Could you give a more complete stack trace?

Comment: That was a great question - the problem was that I had not implemented my resolver.  Once I did this, I was able to decode.